# Assigning NO DATA instead showing blank cells in ssrs 2008 - based on row visibility expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a problem in SSRS 2008 described as below:

I have a matrix which is connected to a query, lets say `Select * from Table`. It is returning, lets say 50 rows of data. In my matrix, there is only one row. Lets say:

```
id   name    grade
[id] [name]  sum[grade]
```

The matrix is grouped by 'id' and 'name' in Row Group. There is a row visibility expression for this row like `=IIF(sum(Fields!grade.Value)>95,false,true)`. Assuming that for this situation, this table shows no data, all the returned 50 rows of data has a grade lower than 95 in total. Therefore, I see only the columns without any information on the screen like:

```
id name grade
```

What I want is to write "No Data" instead' like:

```
id name grade
No Data
```

Normally, when there is no data returning from the query, I would do it by going Tablix Properties and assign "No Data" to the NoRowsMessage property. This is not working for this situation, and I could not figure out how I can count the displayed row number in a matrix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your XML definition for the Matrix and it's properties in your SSRS report please?

Comment: I dont think XML definition of my matrix and its properties is related to my question, the issue is general. Why don't you create a matrix urself and test this situation

Comment: Why don't you share your code so we can replicate your current report and attempt to provide you with answers and a solution far more quickly? Creating a generic report has only shown it working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a row add the end of the tablix and outside the Row Group.

[image]

Once the row is created type `No Data` in the first cell of the row.

[image]

Select the `No Data` row and go to `Row Visibility` property and set this expression:

```
=IIF(
Sum(IIF(Fields!Grade.Value>95,1,0))>0,True,False
)
```

When all rows have Grade 95 or less the No Data row will be shown but the data rows will be hidden.

[image][image]

**UPDATE** Update based on OP's feedback. Grade column is an sum expression.

In that case it is useful use the `LookupSet` function to get the grades by ID. They will be returned in an array data type so we require custom code to sum the ID grades.

Go to `Report` Menu / `Report Properties...`, select the `Code` tab and paste the following code.

```
Dim HiddenFlag as Integer = 0
Function CalculateHiddenFlag(ByVal items As Object()) As Integer
   If items Is Nothing Then
      Return HiddenFlag
   End If
   Dim sumItems As Decimal = New Decimal()
   sumItems = 0
   For Each item As Object In items
      sumItems += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
   Next
   If (sumItems > 95 and HiddenFlag=0) Then
      HiddenFlag = 1
   End If
   Return 0
End Function

Function GetHiddenFlag() As Integer
   Return HiddenFlag
End Function
```

Now modify the `[Sum(Grade)]` cell expression an use this one:

```
=Sum(Fields!Grade.Value)+
Code.CalculateHiddenFlag(
LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!ID.Value,Fields!Grade.Value,"DataSet15"))
```

> Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of yours.

Your matrix should look like this:

[image]

For the `No Data` row visibility property use the following expression:

```
=IIF(Code.GetHiddenFlag()=1,True,False)
```

It will return this when at least one row has Grade > 95.

[image]

And this when there is no rows which Grade is greater than 95.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I notified that there is a groupby expression in the matrix as well and the grade is calculating by SUM(grade). That's why ur suggestion didnot work I believe. I edited my question, may I ask you to check again please when u available?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, are you grouping by Name too or ID and Name are unique values?.

Comment: I am grouping by Name too.

Comment: Does an ID have different Names? ID = 1, Name = NameA, Grade 45. ID=1, Name=NameB, Grade 60. Is this your case?

Comment: ID = 1, Name = A, Grade 45. ID=1, Name=A, Grade 60. ID = 2, Name = B, Grade 22. ID=2, Name=B, Grade 57. etc.  Id and Name always same.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, Check my update. It also can be solved in T-SQL but you will have to share your query.